# Expression of type list(object) doesn't conform to expected list scala

Tags: scala, list, object, append, cumulative-sum

Supposedly I have the following

```
case class test {
                   a:string
                   b: string
                   c: Int
                   d: Int }


var temp = List(test("lol","lel",1,2))
var total = List(test)

total = total:::temp //this doesn't work because temp is of type [test] while total is of type [test.type]
```

I do not understand the difference.
The reason I want to use this is that I want to have a running list where elements will be conditionally added in a loop.
So in this instance, `total` should initially an empty list which takes `test` objects. How do I do this?

Any feedback is appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

Let me begin by explaining few basics about Scala.

In Scala, you define a class like following,

```
scala> class Demo(a: String, b: Int) {
 |   def stringify: String = a + " :: " + b
 | }
// defined class Demo
```

You can think of a `class` as a blueprint given to Scala which will be used to create instances of that `class`. Here, every instance of `class Demo` will have two properties - `a` which will be a `String` and `b` which will be an `Int` and one method - `stringify` which will return a `String`.

```
scala> val demo1 = new Demo("demo1", 1)
// demo1: Demo = Demo@21eee94f

scala> demo1.getClass
// res0: Class[_ <: Demo] = class Demo
```

Here `demo1` is an instance of `class` `Demo` and has `type` `Demo`.

Scala also has a concept of `object` which are instances of specially generated inner classes.

```
scala> object OtherDemo {
 | val a: Int = 10
 | }
// defined object OtherDemo

scala> DemoObject.getClass
// res2: Class[_ <: OtherDemo.type] = class OtherDemo$
```

Here `OtherDemo` will be the only instance of that specially generated `class` `OtherDemo$` and has `type` `OtherDemo.type`.

And then there are `case class` in Scala

```
scala> case class AnotherDemo(a: Int)
// defined class AnotherDemo
```

This will create not only a `class` `AnotherDemo` but also an `object` `AnotherDemo` which we call a companion object. Which is equivalent to,

```
class AnotherDemo(a: Int)

object AnotherDemo {

  def apply(a: Int): AnotherDemo = new AnotherDemo(a)

  def unapply(anotherDemo: AnotherDemo): Option[Int] = Some(anotherDemo.a)

  // And many more utility functions
}
```

We call this `object` `AnotherDemo` as `companion object` of `class` `AnotherDemo`.

We can create instances of `AnotherDemo` in two ways,

```
// By using new keyword, as we can do for any class
scala> val anotherDemo1 = new AnotherDemo(1)
// anotherDemo1: AnotherDemo = AnotherDemo(1)

// Or we can use `apply` method provided by companion object
scala> val anotherDemo2 = AnotherDemo(2)
// anotherDemo2: AnotherDemo = AnotherDemo(2)

scala> anotherDemo1.getClass
// res6: Class[_ <: AnotherDemo] = class AnotherDemo

scala> anotherDemo2.getClass
// res7: Class[_ <: AnotherDemo] = class AnotherDemo

scala> AnotherDemo.getClass
// res8: Class[_ <: AnotherDemo.type] = class AnotherDemo$
```

Also, In Scala your class names should start with Capital Letter. This enables you to easily distinguish them from instance variable which should start with small letters. This helps you in avoiding confusion.

Now, it is supposed to be `a: String` and not `a: string`.

```
scala> case class Test(
 |       a: String,
 |       b: String,
 |       c: Int,
 |       d: Int
 |     )
// defined class Test
```

Now, when you write,

```
scala> var temp = List(Test("lol","lel",1,2))
// temp: List[Test] = List(Test(lol,lel,1,2))
```

It is actually equivalent to,

```
var temp = List.apply(Test.apply("lol","lel",1,2))
```

Or,

```
val test1 = Test.apply("lol","lel",1,2)
var temp = List.apply(test1)
```

The `Test` in `Test.apply` is not your `class Test` but the `companion object Test`. And calling `Test.apply` returns an instance of `class Test`  which is being passed to `List.apply` to finally get a `List` of `type` `List[Test]` containing this instance of `Test`.

But when you write this,

```
scala> var total = List(Test)
// total: List[Test.type] = List(Test)
```

You are creating a `List` of type `List[Test.type]` containing that `companion object` of `Test`.

Focus on `total: List[Test.type]` part... this means that `total` is a `variable` of `type` `List[Test.type]` which means that it will want to point to a `value/instance` of `type` `List[Test.type]`, and will refuse to point to anything else.

Now... you are trying to do this,

```
total = total ::: temp
```

Which is equivalent to,

```
val x = total ::: temp
total = x
```

which is actually,

```
val x = temp.:::(total)
total = x
```

Now look at this `val x = total ::: temp`,

```
scala> val x = total ::: temp
// x: List[Serializable] = List(Test, Test(lol,lel,1,2))
```

You see... this `x` is of type `List[Serializable]`. So when you try `total = x`, you will get following error,

```
scala> total = x
// <console>:13: error: type mismatch;
// found   : List[Serializable]
// required: List[Test.type]
//       total = x
//               ^
```

Which means that `total` required a `List[Test.type]` but you are giving it a `List[Serializable]`.

Comment: Mate your answer is way too long you should always make it as concise as possible

Comment: @JPG I don't think that I am obliged to make my answer "as concise as possible", I will explain things with whatever viewpoint I have.

Comment: Of course mate. Just dont be surprised with down votes.

Comment: This forum is not about making answers "as short as possible". It is more about making sure that you answer the question and help the community.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `total = List.empty[test]` rather than `List(test)`. 
The former creates an empty list of type `List[test]`, the latter is a one-element list of type `List[test.type]` (`test.type` is not the same as `test` - it is its own object, representing the type of instances of `test`).

Also, do not use `var`. They are evil, and not really needed in scala in 99% of uses-cases. Just pretend that keyword does not exist at all, until you get enough of a grip at the language to be able to confidently distinguish the other 1%.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

`var total = List(test)`

You are not initializing the object test, that's why the type of the list is Test.type, you are only creating a list of a template for an object.

When you do this instead:
`var temp = List(test("lol","lel",1,2))`

Yo have the object instantiated from a template (a class, in this case, Test) so the type of temp is `List[Temp]`.

So, if you do something like:

`val template = Test`
Then the type of t is `Test.type`

And you can instantiate an object Test from `template` like this:

`val instantiated = template("lol","lel",1,2)`

As you see in your example, the `total` variable is just a list of templates from where you can instantiate objects while the `temp` variable is a list of objects of type Test.

To create an empty list of objects of type Test you just have to do:

`val t: List[Test] = List.empty`

Then you can add any object (of type `Test`) to this list

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description ('I want to have a running list where elements will be conditionally added in a loop'), my understanding is that you are getting `Test` objects from some source and want to put them in a list but only if they meet certain criteria. We can express this requirement as a method. For convenience, we'll put the method in the `Test` companion object. Companion objects are a place to put things that should be available without having to instantiate any objects.

```
case class Test(a: String, b: String, c: Int, d: Int)

object Test {
  /**
  Returns a list of `Test` objects that pass the given criteria.

  @param tests some source of tests that we can loop over one at a
    time.
  @param condition checks whether a `Test` object should go into our
    output list.
  */
  def runningList(
    tests: Iterable[Test])(condition: Test => Boolean): List[Test] =
    tests.filter(condition).toList
}
```

You can use it like (e.g.):

```
Test.runningList(testsSource) { test => test.c > 0 && test.d < 100 }
```

As you can see here, I've used a few Scala features, like iterables and their list conversion method, multi-parameter-list methods, first-class functions, function-as-last-argument DSL, and so on. If you have more questions on these topics I'd recommend a Scala tutorial.